# how to add a customized Task in the Activiti Modeler

Tags: activiti

how can I add a customized item in the Activiti Modeler?
link for activiti modeler http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html#activitiModeler

Answer (score 0):

The Activiti Modeler is branched from Signavio. So what u r really asking is how to customize Signavio Modeler. You can do it by manipulating Json files in the Modeler. Maybe [this](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2715) will give you a direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using activiti with *jenkins* it will be very easy to create and edit a workflow.
Just Create a new BPMN workflow model in *Jenkins* then Open Activiti Explorer and click on process.
You will see this newly created workflow model in activiti.
There will be an option on the top right side panel  as  "Convert it to Editable model"
Click on that and thats it!
Now You can do editting as per your Requirements!